# Ввести число, найти количество чисел 3?

Tags: python, pygame

Можете показати пример как это делается на библиотеку pygame

Для заданного числа (переменная или то что вводим с консоли) найти количество цифр 3.
Если нету 3-ки тогда какой то printf("нету с 3")
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Подозреваю, что pygame тут ни при чём, для решения достаточно базовых возможностей языка. Вот как на листочке это решить?

Comment: Очень просили именно на этой библе

Comment: Эта библиотека используется для создания компьютерных игр. Каким образом вы хотите её применять для вашей задачи?

Comment: Я вот тоже так подумал, значит ошыбается человек который так хочет

Comment: ош-__ы__-бается ?

Comment: Сорян я Украины, я лучше на англ говорю чем на русс )))

Answer (score 2):

Вот так можно:

```
num = 5467847
if str(num).find('3') == -1:
    print('нет цифры 3')
else:
    print(str(num).count('3'))
```

или ещё так:

```
num = 5467847
print('нет цифры 3' if str(num).find('3') == -1 else str(num).count('3'))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
number = -521335215432
print(str(abs(number)).count('3'))
```

Comment: Не хватает "Если нету 3-ки тогда какой то printf("нету с 3")". Да и абсолютное значение брать необязательно.